# how to change settings every time when I create setup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation, windows-installer

I have developed a wpf application for a client and I dont want to give the source code. Since the client wants to change the logo and few links in the application for his different set of users, how can I give a functionality for him to create a setup with different settings each time?

I thought of giving the debug folder so that he can change the exe.config and create the setup with Inno setup. is this the right way or can you please guide me another solution?

Thanks,
Venkz

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, can you please explain a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create an "app.config" (application configuration) file? It's just a simple XML file with defined syntaxes or you can define your own configuration settings.

For more info about this, see this on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kza1yk3a.aspx

Comment: is there any way to rebuild the exe by changing the resources but without the code? I mean, my client should be able to change the icon of the application for every setup creation.

Comment: What if you change properties for your icon file. Set Build Action to None and Copy to Output Directory to true? Then you should be able to change the file after build?

Comment: @Daniel, Thanks for you reply, I did like what you did but though the file is copied to the output folder,while installing its not pasting it. However, I solved the issue by writing a custom script in the Innosetup script file

Comment: Yes, you can. Your installer (using MSI script) can point to the app.config file too.